# llvm : how to cache some 'native/jitted' code and restore it

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm working on a 'query engine', this one use LLVM to convert the queries into native code. For this I use a JIT execution engine.

But, I can have a lot of different queries, but I can also repeat the same query a thousand of times !

So, my goal is to 'cache' the native code generated by the execution engine.
Is it possible ?

I need to store the 'native' code in a buffer and restore it later for execution !

Each query has its own hash-code, so it is easy to manage a cache and recognize a similar query.

My main problem is to store and restore the native code, and avoiding the recompilation/optimization/jit steps !

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: boost::lru_cache<std::string, std::shared_ptr<YourJIT>> jitCache(20); to get a cache for up to 20 jit-compiled results keying by hash in string format and flushing whatever's least recently used.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a cache (LRU or whatever) ! I just need to know how to extract and restore the native code from LLVM ;-)

Comment: The Module you make contains the Function objects you want to cache and run, as shown in chapter four of the kaleidoscope tutorial. If I understand you correctly, you're adamant about not wanting to keep the Module, only the stuff in the module. I don't know how to do that, personally I'd just cache the Module. The Module may have some overhead but I'd personally ignore that until it becomes a known problem.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that add/removing modules is a solution. But on the ExecutionEngine there is no way to remove all the modules ! Even, I'm not sure we can push/pop any module from this EE, not sure it is designed for ? Right ?

Comment: FYI, for now I cache both the ExecutionEngine and the Module. But I'm not sure it is the best way. I want to reuse the same ExecutionEngine, but does it make sense ?

Comment: IMO the question is whether it hurts. Is it one of your top three RAM wasters?

Comment: I don't really care about RAM, but more about CPU performance ! The JIT code is small (only small code portion). But I have read somewhere that creating an ExecutionEngine is expensive ;-)

Comment: You could achieve this using new ORC JIT APIs. I will try to elaborate a bit later.